# Beginner question about site hosting and traffic forwarding on domains

Tags: web-hosting

We have a public IP address assigned to the router in our Company.  We also have public domains hosted at our internet service provider.  I have access to modify those domains through Plesk. (one is for ASP.NET,  another is for PHP).  Now I can get an idea of traffic patterns through my router up to my server.

*I am at the early stages of making WEB applications and to show others my work I would rather like to give an address with my domain or subdomain to end users*

**Sample:**

1. If someone calls www.mydomain.com he will get my public web site hosted on our internet service provider,
2. If someone calls testapp.mydomain.com, Plesk will redirect the call to my IP address and so on to my server
3. Else if someone calls mydomain.com/testapp, Plesk will also redirect them to my public IP (router)

Comment: Why DownVoting ?

Comment: Not sure. SF seems unusually cranky today.

Comment: Sorry for awful grammar, Maybe because of that I got bad reputation or it is just Monday.

Comment: Not sure why you're being downvoted, but I'm not seeing a question.

Comment: @GregD My mistake I should section Sample change with Questions, How to do or Requesting Scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if Plesk lets you modify DNS entires or not, but what you will need is to create an A or host record for testapp.mydmoan.com that points to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (your IP address) with a TTL of 8 hours.

You are probably better off just opening a support ticket and asking your ISP to add that DNS entry for you.

Then create a directory under mydomain.com called testapp.  In that directory, create a new file called index.html.  In that file, place the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Page Title</title>
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://testapp.mydomain.com">
</HEAD>
<BODY>
Optional page text here.
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Users going to mydomain.com/testapp will see a brief flash of text (whatever is between the  tags, then be redirected to testapp.mydomain.com

Alternatively, pay $10 for another domain name that belongs to you rather than "we" and point it where ever you like.